# Find the $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1}g_n(x)dx$ for these functions

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, sequence-of-function

The sequence of the continuous functions $f_n$ on the $I= [-1,1]$ satisfies $(a)$~$(c)$ [Here  $\mathbb{N}$ is the natural number set]

$(a)$ $f_n(x) \geq 0 $ for $\forall x \in  I$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$(b)$  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ , $\int_{-1}^{1}f_n(x) dx =1$

$(c)$ For all $a$ which is $0 < a <1$, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{a \leq \vert x \vert \leq 1}f_n(x)dx=0 $

Put the $g_n(x) = \int_{-1}^{1}f_n(t)e^{x-t}dt $ which is $g_n : [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$. Find the value of  $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1}g_n(x)dx$.

In solution sheet, It found the value by using epsilon-delta technique. It used the definition of the uniformly convergence. But I tried different ways like the below.

From the $(b)$, $1= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_{-1}^{1}f_n(x) dx =   \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}f_n(x) dx + \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_{\frac{1}{n}\leq\vert x \vert \leq 1}f_n(x) dx$.

Then By $(c)$, $1= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}f_n(x) dx $

The question requires $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1}g_n(x)dx = (e-1) \{\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}f_n(x)e^{-x} dx + \int_{\frac{1}{n}\leq\vert x \vert \leq 1}f_n(x)e^{-x} dx \}$.

First, By the mean value thm of the integral, I got $ \int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}f_n(x)e^{-x} dx = e^{-{c_n}}\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}f_n(x) dx$ for the $c_n\in (- \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$
So I deduced  $1= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}f_n(x)e^{-x} dx $.

Second from the $(a)$, $e^{-1} \int_{\frac{1}{n}\leq\vert x \vert \leq 1}f_n(x) dx  \leq  \int_{\frac{1}{n}\leq\vert x \vert \leq 1}e^{-x}f_n(x) dx \leq  e\int_{\frac{1}{n}\leq\vert x \vert \leq  1}f_n(x) dx $ for  the $x \in [-1,1]$

By squeeze thm and $(c)$, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_{\frac{1}{n} \leq \vert x \vert \leq 1}f_n(x)e^{-x} dx = 0$ .

When we back to the point of the $g_n$, the value would be $(e-1)$ considering the first and second arguments.

Is my solution is right? If not please let me know which point I've missed. Thank you.

Comment: You are applying c) with $a$ dependent on $n$. This is not allowed.